# Como criar um formato padrão de digitação num formulário do Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tipo: abc@def

Obrigatoriamente deve ter um (@) no meio entre os sete caracteres digitados.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa para resolver isso é criar um métodos para validação usando [`android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#EMAIL_ADDRESS). Veja como ficaria:

```
public static boolean validEmail(CharSequence str) {
    return str != null && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(str).matches();
}
```

Para verificar podes usar o metodo `addTextChangeListener` para seu `EditText`. Veja como ficaria:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            if(validEmail(s))
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else Log.wtf("TAG","ERRO");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
});
```

Veja mais detalhes sobre `Patterns` [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#).

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta!

Mas poderia informar onde adiciono estes métodos e funções?
Há algum tutorial disponível?

Comment: @RealidadeAumentada você primeiro para desenvolver Android, precisa ter conceitos básicos de JAVA. Na internet você vai encontrar milhões de tutoriais. No entanto, a documentação é basicamente o melhor lugar para aprender.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @RealidadeAumentada conseguiu implementar? Se a resposta foi útil, pode validar se quiser. abs